# Javascript not working on downloaded websites

Tags: javascript, ajax

So recently I was looking at some well-designed websites, with the functionality that I want to achieve / learn.

However, the problem is, that even though I manage to download the complete website (most recently I was using Scrapbook from Firefox), the website is not fully functional. Seems like the JS isn't working..

For example, a page like [this](http://www.livelygreen.com/themes/highgrove/). 
When downloaded, the animations, progressive loading etc. are missing. I am guessing it's using Ajax to communicate with the server then?

Or what's the reason? Is there a way to get it working?

Cheers.

Comment: Probably being loaded dynamically, and too complex for the tool you are using to resolve all the resources. You might be able to infer where the resources are located and download them manually with a bit of detective work looking through the source code.

Answer (score -1):

Most probably this is due to some scripts needing to be served from a domain name instead of localhost (your local machine). Your best bet is to learn how to set up a local web server with a package like [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org) or [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/). This is useful way beyond serving downloaded sites to inspect how they work. You can actually have a complete development environment this way.

Bonus tip: check out sites like [Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/) to learn even more about the ins and outs of web programming languages.